# Can the mass of longitudinal and transverse W bosons be measured separately?

Tags: particle-physics, weak-interaction, electroweak, bosons

Some higgsless unified models of particle physics predict that the mass of longitudinally polarized W bosons and the mass of transversely polarized W bosons are different.

In those models, a difference in masses is also predicted to appear for the Z boson.

Is there a way that the existing data from the LHC, the LEP or the Tevatron can be used to check this prediction? Or maybe it has already been checked?

Comment: Hi Clara, and welcome to Physics Stack Exchange! Excellent question :-) I'm not very familiar with the models you're talking about, so I could only speculate at an answer, but I do hope someone knowledgeable comes along to answer this.

Comment: Please give a reference to ''Some higgsless unified models of particle physics predict''

Comment: It is hard enough to measure the mass of the W since there are always missing neutrals in its decay, so I would not expect an experiment to be easy. The Z is a different story and somebody might be intrigued to check polarisations versus mass. In any case if a large mass difference existed one would have seen a secondary peak when scanning the Z:http://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/docs/00/00/82/46/PDF/democrite-00004641.pdf

Comment: Anna, but polarization changes continuously, so one would expect a smooth superposition of Gaussians, not a secondary peak. To see two distinct peaks, one would need to separate exact longitudinal and exact transversal polarization only, leaving out all the intermediate orientations. Is that possible?

Comment: If there were a large mass difference in the two polarizations it would show as a bump, since each individual Z would be of a specific polarization, fixed for that Z once produced. Take Z going to e+e-. It will have one specific pollarisation, it is a particle.

Comment: Isn't 'transversal' and 'perpendicular' defined with reference to the beam direction? Can't a particle be polarized in any direction in between, especially if the beam is not fully polarized?

Comment: The models can't make any sense--- can you point to a reference? There is no way the Higgs isn't there.

Comment: Your request is not helpful for the answer. The question was: Is there a way that the existing data from the LHC, the LEP or the Tevatron can be used to check that longitudinal and transverse mass differ? Or maybe it has already been checked?